# GetGeotagAsync fails on files from a list created via Folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions w/ OrderByName

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

Objective: get a list of image files from a user specified folder and retrieve the latitude/longitude metadata for each file if available.

The approach is to use Folder query with options to return a list of files which are then iterated over to get the geotag info. As a simple test I just added some code to the Geotag sample provided by MS; ChooseFolderButton_Click method added. It uses FolderPicker then simply picks the first file from the query (just as a test) and treats it like the original demo does to display geotag info.

The problem appears to be with how the StorageFile items are returned from the query AND only when CommonFileQuery.OrderByName is used. If DefaultQuery is used then all works.

Here is the code added to MS Samples Geotag (a button was added to the XAML):

```
private async void ChooseFolderButton_Click()
{
    FolderPicker picker = new FolderPicker
    {
        SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary,
        CommitButtonText = "Select",
        ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
    };
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    StorageFolder Folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

    if (Folder != null) { 
        // Get the files and sort them myself
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await Folder.GetFilesAsync();
        List<StorageFile> sortedList = files.Where(f => string.Compare(f.FileType,".jpg", ignoreCase: true) == 0 )
                                                .OrderBy(f => f.DisplayName)
                                                .Select(f => f)
                                                .ToList();
        file = sortedList.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    if (Folder != null) {
        // Use Folder GetFiles with query options to get sorted list
        var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, new List<string> { ".jpg" })
        {
            FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Shallow
        };
            //queryOptions.SetPropertyPrefetch(PropertyPrefetchOptions.ImageProperties, null);
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files2 = await Folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions).GetFilesAsync();
        var file2 = files2[0];
    }

    if (Folder != null && file != null)
    {
        FileDisplayName.Text = file.DisplayName;
        FileOperationsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        FileOperationsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Selecting the file from sortedList works fine. Using the result from files2 will also work when DefaultQuery is used as shown. Change it to OrderByName and the GetGeotagAsync call will fail, returning null.

Looking into it in detail, it appears the StorageFile instance returned is different in this last case.  The FolderRelativeId has the file extension duplicated; numbers\filename.ext.ext ; however, access through the StorageFile instance seems to work otherwise... except for GetGeotagAsync() at a minimum. This makes me wonder if a copy of the files are being created and the metadata is not included.

I am relatively new to C# and UWP and this is my first question post so I hope this is enough detail... The Question is basically: Am I missing something here? Doing something wrong in the Folder Query? I can work around it using linq as I did in the example code, or even just use DefaultQuery; yet this is uncomfortable as I do use the folder query approach in several other things. Does query OrderByName duplicate or do something undesireable?

Comment: this looks like a bug on the platform, and nothing is missing at your end.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that those acquired files will be displayed to the ui,
if this is the case, you can use the nifty **AdvancedCollectionView** that is part of Windows Community Toolkit.

AdvancedCollectionView allows for a persistent sorting as well as filtering of contained items based on their properties, a proccess that makes it incredibly usefull for modern binding intensive apps.

Here is an example:

```
List<StorageFile> FileList = New List<StorageFile>();

Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.AdvancedCollectionView ObservableFileList
        {
            get; set;
        }




void InitializeList(){

//here we pass the backing list as an argument, 
//any changes on the filelist will be directly reflected on our new observablelist, and vice versa

ObservableFileList = new Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.AdvancedCollectionView(FileList);

//here we add sorting definitions, 
//"DisplayName" is the current property we choose to sort against

ObservableFileList.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("DisplayName",SortDirection.Descending)); 

}


void AcquireNewDataSet(){    
//GetFiles should return your files with no particular order.    
List<StorageFile>tmp = GetFiles();    

//always prefer ReplaceRange
FileList.ReplaceRange(tmp);    
}
```

following this process, your observable list will always be alphabetically sorted, even when using it as **ItemSource** on various UI Item Containers

Comment: Thanks for the information on AdvancedCollectionView, I need to explore the toolkit more. However, in this case I simply list the items in name order and display on map per gps coordinates. I was concerned with the behavior of the folder query mostly. I appreciate the info it will help.

Comment: Yeah the list will also work sorted in code to use on your map, please don't forget to mark the answer as valid